# how to get task those are not in any queue in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am using CRM 2011 on-Premisis. I have a portal in which client create a ticket(task in crm) and it goes in specific queue line (CS Queue,EDI Queue, Lab Quue). But some tasks created but do not goes in any quue. How I get these taks which are not in any queue.

If anyone have an idea please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Riaz Usmani

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can try to use Left Outer Join to get your data. I've built provided query based on following article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531006.aspx Try it:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
  <entity name="task">
    <attribute name="activityid" />
    <attribute name="subject" />
    <link-entity name="queueitem" from="objectid" to="activityid" alias="ab" link-type="outer">
       <attribute name="objectid" />
    </link-entity>
    <filter type="and">
        <condition entityname="ab" attribute="objectid" operator="null" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
<fetch/>
```

Comment: That's a good point, Guido. In this case it would be required to fetch all tasks and after check one-by-one does it belong to any queue or not. Or as an alternative way - add bit field to a task, call it Belongs To Queue with false as a default value, develop plugin that will handle events of adding/removal of a task to/from queue and update custom field with correspond value. After that this field could be used in Advanced Fiend and Views.